# Требуется передать в определенную страницу HTML данные из БД FastAPI

Tags: javascript, python, fastapi

Всем привет. На днях на курсах по Python начали изучать FastAPI. Ну, после первого занятия понятно что толком ничего не понятно) Дали задачку, факультативно - реализовать форму регистрации, полученные с формы данные писать в БД, и выводить список пользователей из нее же.
С записью особых проблем не возникло, базового руководства с просторов инета вполне хватило. А вот с выводом не заладилось - в руководстве все реализовано на одной странице HTML, а у меня несколько. Используются шаблоны Jinja2Templates. Код бэка:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Body, Depends
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import  Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# строка подключения
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///./users.db"
 
# создаем движок SqlAlchemy
engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}
)
#создаем базовый класс для моделей
Base = declarative_base()
 
# создаем модель, объекты которой будут храниться в бд
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    email = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)
 
# создаем таблицы
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

app = FastAPI() # <- Создаем экземпляр класса FastAPI
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@app.get("/") # <- декоратор, который обрабатывает get - запросы где маршрут
def index(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse(request=request, name='index.html')

@app.get("/login/") # <- декоратор, который обрабатывает get - запросы где маршрут
def login(request:Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse(request=request, name="login.html")
 
@app.get("/users/") # <- декоратор, который обрабатывает get - запросы где маршрут
def get_users_page(request:Request):
    SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autoflush=False, bind=engine)
    db = SessionLocal()
    users = db.query(Person).all()
    return templates.TemplateResponse(request=request, name="users.html", context=users)

@app.post("/rec/")
def add_us(data = Body()):
    SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autoflush=False, bind=engine)
    db = SessionLocal()
    new_email = data["mail"]
    new_password = data["pass"]
    user = Person(email = new_email, password = new_password)
    db.add(user)
    db.commit()


# uvicorn main:app --reload
```

на принимающей стороне страницы users код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
      button {
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 20px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 30px;
        }
</style>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Users</h1>

    <h2 style="text-align: center";>Список пользователей</h2>
  
    <table style="display: block; margin: auto;">
        <thead><tr><th>Email</th><th>Password</th><th>ID</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody id="table">
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button onclick="back()">На главную</button>
    <button onclick="reg()">На форму регистрации</button>

  <script defer>
        // Получение всех пользователей
        async function getUsers() {
            // отправляет запрос и получаем ответ
            const response = await fetch("/users/", {
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json" }
            });
            // если запрос прошел нормально
            if (response.ok === true) {
                // получаем данные
                const users = await response.json();
                const table = document.querySelector("#table");
                users.forEach(user => table.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", `<tr><th>${user["email"]}</th><th>${user["password"]}</th>${user["id"]}<th>ID</th></tr>`));
            }
        }
        function back() {
            window.location.href='/'
        }
        function reg() {
            window.location.href='/login/'
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

И в общем ничего не срабатывает корректно. понимаю что список передавать в контекст шаблона не хочет - но я делал из него словарь, тогда в терминале все ок, статусы зеленые - но на странице юзерс он ничего не получает, пробовал консолить переменную.
В общем вся проблема - запихать список словарей в контекст и передать в определенную страницу через шаблон

Понимаю что вопрос скорее всего простейший, да и я скорее всего наворотил бреда - но еще ж ничего не знаю вообще про запросы и проч. Инфы в инете просто вагон, но как я заметил - не для чайников типа меня. Что сделать или хотя бы где конкретно копать для решения?

Comment: Я пробовал его запихать в body onload - тоже ничего. Это изначальный код, по аналогии из учебной статьи, без экспериментов

Comment: Что то то ли я дурак то ли лыжи не едут)) по ссылке пустое окно визуализатора или что это там

Comment: @Bald что то заработало, но выводит просто 1 1 1 1 ID, 2 2 2 ID...  каждой строке. не могу скрин прицепить. Я так понимаю, нужно в resolve([{
              id: 1,
              email: 1,
              password: 1
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              email: 2,
              password: 2
            },
            {
              id: 3,
              email: 3,
              password: 3
            },
          ]); переменные какие то воткнуть?

Comment: уточнение: это сработало, когда я убрал из @app.get("/users/") 
def get_users_page(request:Request):
    SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autoflush=False, bind=engine)
    db = SessionLocal()
    users = db.query(Person).all()
    return templates.TemplateResponse(request=request, name="users.html", context=users) context=users, ибо он как не хотел принимать в контекст список - так и не хочет, ошибка 500. если возвращать список из функции - как попасть тогда на страницу users? redirectом?

Comment: у Вас сервер FastApi запускается? что показывает команда `uvicorn main:app --reload` попробуйте в браузере получить список пользователей url/users/, где где адрес сервера FastApi

Comment: Да, работает, в терминале идет трассировка постоянно, юзеры  в бд добавляются с другой html. url/users - {"detail":"Not Found"}

Comment: если все еще актуально, то может стоит на сервере выделить api методы для обработки запросов от клиентов, т.е. get /users/ возвращает страницу а get /api/users возвращает список пользователей